# How do I load external scripts into my Chrome extension?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm trying to pop open a tab with the Facebook login sample code, from within my Chrome extension. I'm using straight up tutorial code in this example so far.

The tab opens up properly, however, facebook's javascript fails to load due to a cross site security policy issue, and I'm getting an inline script error, too - which seems odd (unless maybe dynamically added elements have inline script which triggers the error message?)

Where can I learn how to properly do this kind of thing?

Errors:

```
Refused to load script from 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js' because of Content-Security-Policy.
Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'popup.html'})
```

popup.html: //sample login code from facebook api documentation

```
  <head>
    <title>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>

    </script>

    <h1>Facebook Client-side Authentication Example</h1>
      <div id="auth-status">
        <div id="auth-loggedout">
          <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display:none">
          Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>  
        (<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js://sample code from facebook dev

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
        ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '', // App ID
        channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel', // Path to your Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true // parse XFBML
    });

    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
            FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                if (me.name) {
                    document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                }
            })
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
    document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function () {
        FB.login();
    });
    document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function () {
        FB.logout();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html would be a good start, as would ["An Introduction to Content Security Policy"](http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) on HTML5Rocks.

In this case, it looks like you'll need to whitelist https://connect.facebook.net; you can do that by adding `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net; object-src 'self'"` to your `manifest.json` file.

The inline script error is possibly due to the empty `script` tag in `popup.html`, but may also be due to something Facebook's scripts are injecting into the page. Only one way to find out... :)

Comment: if you want to whitelist multiple domains, separate them with a single space followed by a semi colon at the end of the list, and you can also include a wildcard * to capture domain variations like: https://*.facebook.* https://*.google.com https://www.apple.com;

Comment: Damn!  must all my visitors do this too? My `manifest.json` ???? where?